# java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException:

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

when i tried to execute jenkins build, error occurs - java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException.Please confirm what changes need to be done to avoid this issue. My script is powershell

```
##The below error occurs in jenkins
   Also:   java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1

        at java.base/java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:275)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:307)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:132)
        at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:205)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:120)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:268)
        at hudson.FilePath$CreateTextTempFile.invoke(FilePath.java:1656)

#   Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temp file on C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\On-premise server

    at hudson.FilePath.createTextTempFile(FilePath.java:1624)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.createScriptFile(CommandInterpreter.java:202)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:120)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:92)
    at hudson.plugins.powershell.PowerShell.perform(PowerShell.java:48)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1895)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```